# How to store multiple date to event relations(schedules) efficiently

Tags: java

I have schedules such as :

```
Time     Events
----     ------
1week    a,b,c
2week    b,c
5month   d,j
8month   m,n
7week    c,f
10year   a
6year    g
```

How can i store these most efficiently in a java application in an OO model, so that I can easily create schedules starting at a particular date?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - most common schedules model events with a start time, end time/duration and/or repetitions.

Comment: @Smutje Exactly, I don't want to create a solution that already exist, my events only has a start time btw.